# Add to ListArray from Array

Tags: java, android

For an array, how can i take all the values at even indexes and add to nameArray and all the values at odd indexes and add to scoreArray? I got this code but it isn't working.

```
String[] inputArray = {"john", "10", "frank", "14"}

for (int j = 0; j == inputArray.length; j++) {
    if ((j % 2) == 0) {
        nameArr.add(inputArray[j]);
        } else {
        scoreArr.add(inputArray[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I understand right you want to add the elements of inputArray? But then why use split2[]?

Comment: sorry just changed the name of the array to inputArray for comfort reading, just failed to change it all, but it's done now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mean `for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++)`

`j == inputArray.length` is evaluated to false at the first iteration so your loop doesn't run.

However, you could get rid of the if statement (assuming that your `inputArray` always contains a name associated a score, i.e always contains pair values) :

```
for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j+=2) {
    nameArr.add(inputArray[j]);
    scoreArr.add(inputArray[j+1]);
}
```

Or you could also use a `Map<String, Integer>` to associate each name with its corresponding score (assuming names are unique) :

```
for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j+=2) 
     m.put(inputArray[j], Integer.parseInt(inputArray[j+1]));
```

Comment: Why you got to beat me to it?  |=^P

Comment: @user3052244 You can read this for more informations about the for statement, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean to have a `<` in your loop and not a `==` and also, try using `inputArray` and not `split2[]` like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
    if ((j % 2) == 0) {
        nameArr.add(inputArray[j]);
        } else {
        scoreArr.add(inputArray[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is look through each element in the array, to do this you want to go through every element starting at 0 and ending at the lengthof the array -1 (because arrays are 0 indexed). Once you are in the loop you want to check if it is an even or odd number using the modulo operator.

```
for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++){
    if ((j % 2) == 0) {
        nameArr.add(inputArray[j];
    } else {
        scoreArr.add(inputArray[j];
    }
}
```